# Resizing Cell in excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to link data from an Excel sheet, copy them to another sheet, and then copy onto another workbook. The data is non-contiguous, and the amount of iterations I need is unknown.

A portion of the code that I have now is below:

```
Sub GetCells()
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim test As Boolean
    x = 0
    i = 0

test = False
Do Until test = True
Windows("Room Checksums.xls").Activate

'This block gets the room name
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("B6").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("A1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(x, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

'This block gets the area
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("AN99").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("B1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(x, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

i = i + 108
x = x + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("B6").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Select
test = ActiveCell.Value = ""
Loop

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, 12)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("GetReference.xlsm").Activate
Range("A8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

End Sub
```

The problem is that it is copying and pasting each cell one by one, flipping between sheets in the process. What I'd like to do is select a number of scattered cells, offset by 108 cells, and select the next number of scattered cells (re-sizing).

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: How do you determine what cells ? Also, you should note that in VBA it's almost never necessary to use ".Select" or ".Activate". This leads to very redundant and error prone code. For example, the first block in the while loop can be written as such: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Offset(i, 0).Copy` effectively converting 4 lines of code into 1 and removing all those ugly selects.

Comment: Here I have rewritten your code into a more condensed version without changing the logic (I hope). This does not solve your problem but it should help you learn better VBA standards.

http://pastebin.com/Wwd3zzYF

Comment: I will refer to worksheet "Sheet1" of workbook "Room Checksums.xls", worksheet "Sheet2" of workbook "Room Checksums.xls" and active worksheet of workbook "GetReference.xlsm" as SheetA, SheetB and SheetC. Your code first pastes links into SheetB to values in SheetA.  It then pastes links into SheetC to the links in SheetB. This means that if SheetA is updated by the user, SheetB is updated by Excel and then SheetC is updated by Excel. Did you mean to paste links rather than values? Do you need SheetB which doubles the number of updates?

Comment: just a quick thought but couldn't you do this with formulas thus avoiding VBA and you loop altogether?

Comment: could you write in your question how you decide which cells to copy?
I think you should be able to copy an entire block in one step rather than 1 by one, plus you as Alexandre says, no need to select cells or worksheets, just reference the cells and ranges...

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: you should add your code in pastebin as an answer...the only thing missing is selecting an entire block of cells! +1

Comment: Actually I'm not too sure what OP needed. I just rewrote his code so that it would be more compact. I'm waiting for OP before actually answering.

Comment: If I have understood it, your code creates links in `Cells(1+i,"A")` and `Cells(1+i,"B")` of Sheet2 to `Cells(6+108i,"B")` and `Cells(99+108i,"AN")` of Sheet1 where i is 0, 1, 2 and so on until `Cells(6+108i,"B") = ""`.  What is the significance of 6, 99 and 108?  You say the displayed code is a portion.  Are there other similar collections?  If Phillip's suggestion of formulae does not appeal, I believe you need to parameterise this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been studying the end result of your macro.  My objective is to identify a better approach to achieving that result rather than tidying your existing approach.

You name your two workbooks: "Room Checksums.xls" and "GetReference.xlsm".  "xls" is the extension of an Excel 2003 workbook.  "xlsm" is the extension of a post-2003 workbook that contains macros.  Perhaps you are using these extensions correctly but you should check.

I use Excel 2003 so all my workbooks have an extension of "xls".  I suspect you will need to change this.

I have created three workbooks: "Room Checksums.xls", "GetReference.xls" and "Macros.xls".  "Room Checksums.xls" and "GetReference.xls" contain nothing but data.  The macros are in "Macros.xls".  I use this division when only privileged users can run the macros and I do not wish ordinary users to be bothered by or have access to those macros.  My macro below can be placed without changes within "GetReference.xls" if you prefer.

The image below shows worksheet “Sheet1” of "Room Checksums.xls".  I have hidden most of the rows and columns because they contain nothing relevant to your macro.  I have set the cell values to their addresses for my convenience but there is no other significance to these values.

[image: “Sheet1” of "Room Checksums.xls"]

I ran your macro.  “Sheet2” of "Room Checksums.xls" became:

[image: “Sheet2” of "Room Checksums.xls"]

Note: the formula bar shows cell A1 as `=Sheet1!$B$6`.  That is, this is a link not a value.

The active worksheet of "GetReference.xls” became:

[image: active worksheet of "GetReference.xls”]

Note 1: the zeros in columns C to L are because you move 12 columns.  I assume there is other data in these columns of “Sheet2” of your "Room Checksums.xls" that you want.

Note 2: the formula bar shows cell A8 as `='[Room Checksums.xls]Sheet2'!A1`.

My macro achieves the same result as yours but in a somewhat different manner.  However, there are a number of features to my macro which I need to explain.  They are not strictly necessary but I believe they represent good practice.

Your macro contains a lot of what I call magic numbers.  For example: B6, AN99, 108 and A8.  It is possible that these values are meaningful to your company but I suspect they are accidents of the current workbooks.  You use the value 108 several times.  If this value were to change to 109, you would have to search your code for 108 and replace it by 109.  The number 108 is sufficiently unusual for it to be unlikely that it occurs in your code for other reasons but other numbers may not be so unusual making replacement a painstaking task.  At the moment you may know what this number means.  Will you remember when you return to amend this macro in 12 months?

I have defined 108 as a constant:

```
  Const Offset1 As Long = 108
```

I would prefer a better name but I do not know what this number is.  You could replace all occurrences of “Offset1” with a more meaningful name.  Alternatively, you could add comments explaining what it is.  If the value becomes 109, one change to this statement fixes the problem.  I think most of my names should be replaced with something more meaningful.

You assume "Room Checksums.xls" and "GetReference.xlsm" are open.  If one of both of them were not open, the macro would stop on the relevant activate statement.  Perhaps an earlier macro has opened these workbooks but I have added code to check that they are open.

My macro does not paste anything.  It has three phases:

- Work down worksheet “Sheet1” of "Room Checksums.xls" to identify last non-empty cell in the sequence: B6, B114, B222, B330, B438, ... .
- Create links to these entries (and the AN99 series) in worksheet “Sheet2” of "Room Checksums.xls".  Formulae are just strings which start with the symbol “=” and they can be created like any other string.
- Create links in worksheet “Xxxxxx” of "GetReference.xls” to the table in “Sheet2” of "Room Checksums.xls".  I do not like relying on the correct worksheet being active.  You will have to replace “Xxxxxx” with the correct value.

In my macro I have attempted to explain what I am doing but I have not said much about the syntax of the statements I am using.  You should have little difficulty finding explanations of the syntax but do ask if necessary.

I think you will find some of my statements confusing.  For example:

```
    .Cells(RowSrc2Crnt, Col1Src2).Value = "=" & WshtSrc1Name & "!$" & Col1Src1 & _
                                          "$" & Row1Src1Start + OffsetCrnt
```

None of the names are as meaningful as I would like because I do not understand the purpose of the worksheets, columns and offset.  Instead of copying and pasting, I am building a formula such as “=Sheet1!$B$6”.  If you work through the expression you should be able to relate each term with an element of the formula:

```
"="                              =
WshtSrc1Name                     Sheet1
"!$"                             !$
Col1Src1                         B
"$"                              $
Row1Src1Start + OffsetCrnt       6
```

This macro is not quite as I would have coded it for myself since I prefer to use arrays rather than access worksheets directly.  I decided that I was introducing more than enough concepts without the addition of arrays.

Even without arrays this macro is more difficult for a newbie to understand than I had expected when I started coding it.  It is divided into three separate phases each with a separate purpose which should help a little.  If you study it, I hope you can see why it would be easier to maintain if the format of the workbooks changed.  If you have large volumes of data, this macro would be substantially faster than yours.

```
Option Explicit

   Const ColDestStart As Long = 1

   Const Col1Src1 As String = "B"
   Const Col2Src1 As String = "AN"

   Const Col1Src2 As String = "A"
   Const Col2Src2 As String = "B"
   Const ColSrc2Start As Long = 1
   Const ColSrc2End As Long = 12

   Const Offset1 As Long = 108

   Const RowDestStart As Long = 8
   Const Row1Src1Start As Long = 6
   Const Row2Src1Start As Long = 99

   Const RowSrc2Start As Long = 1

   Const WbookDestName As String = "GetReference.xls"
   Const WbookSrcName As String = "Room Checksums.xls"

   Const WshtDestName As String = "Xxxxxx"
   Const WshtSrc1Name As String = "Sheet1"
   Const WshtSrc2Name As String = "Sheet2"

Sub GetCellsRevised()

   Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
   Dim ColSrc2Crnt As Long
   Dim InxEntryCrnt As Long
   Dim InxEntryMax As Long
   Dim InxWbookCrnt As Long
   Dim OffsetCrnt As Long
   Dim OffsetMax As Long
   Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
   Dim RowSrc2Crnt As Long
   Dim WbookDest As Workbook
   Dim WbookSrc As Workbook

   ' Check the source and destination workbooks are open and create references to them.

   Set WbookDest = Nothing
   Set WbookSrc = Nothing

   For InxWbookCrnt = 1 To Workbooks.Count
     If Workbooks(InxWbookCrnt).Name = WbookDestName Then
       Set WbookDest = Workbooks(InxWbookCrnt)
     ElseIf Workbooks(InxWbookCrnt).Name = WbookSrcName Then
       Set WbookSrc = Workbooks(InxWbookCrnt)
    End If
   Next

   If WbookDest Is Nothing Then
     Call MsgBox("I need workbook """ & WbookDestName & """ to be open", vbOKOnly)
     Exit Sub
   End If

   If WbookSrc Is Nothing Then
     Call MsgBox("I need workbook """ & WbookSrcName & """ to be open", vbOKOnly)
     Exit Sub
   End If

  ' Phase 1.  Locate the last non-empty cell in the sequence: B6, B114, B222, ...
  ' within source worksheet 1

  OffsetCrnt = 0

  With WbookSrc.Worksheets(WshtSrc1Name)
    Do While True
      If .Cells(Row1Src1Start + OffsetCrnt, Col1Src1).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      OffsetCrnt = OffsetCrnt + Offset1
    Loop
  End With

  If OffsetCrnt = 0 Then
     Call MsgBox("There is no data to reference", vbOKOnly)
     Exit Sub
  End If

  OffsetMax = OffsetCrnt - Offset1

  ' Phase 2.  Build table in source worksheet 2

  RowSrc2Crnt = RowSrc2Start

  With WbookSrc.Worksheets(WshtSrc2Name)
    For OffsetCrnt = 0 To OffsetMax Step Offset1
      .Cells(RowSrc2Crnt, Col1Src2).Value = "=" & WshtSrc1Name & "!$" & Col1Src1 & _
                                            "$" & Row1Src1Start + OffsetCrnt
      .Cells(RowSrc2Crnt, Col2Src2).Value = "=" & WshtSrc1Name & "!$" & Col2Src1 & _
                                            "$" & Row2Src1Start + OffsetCrnt
      RowSrc2Crnt = RowSrc2Crnt + 1
    Next
  End With

  ' Phase 3.  Build table in destination worksheet

  RowSrc2Crnt = RowSrc2Start
  RowDestCrnt = RowDestStart

  With WbookDest.Worksheets(WshtDestName)
    For OffsetCrnt = 0 To OffsetMax Step Offset1
      ColDestCrnt = ColDestStart
      For ColSrc2Crnt = ColSrc2Start To ColSrc2End
        .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt).Value = _
              "='[" & WbookSrcName & "]" & WshtSrc2Name & "'!" & _
              ColNumToCode(ColSrc2Crnt) & RowSrc2Crnt
        ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1
      Next
      RowSrc2Crnt = RowSrc2Crnt + 1
      RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
    Next
  End With

End Sub
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim Code As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    Code = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      Code = Chr(65 + PartNum) & Code
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = Code

End Function
```

Comment: +1 nice work - but I'm not sure that  the OP will acknowledge your effort

Comment: Thanks for the +1.  You may be correct but I hope not since I suspect the requirement is a lot more complex than the question suggests. I doubt any simplification of the original method will be viable if there are multiple extractions.  The second set of links suggest there are 12 extractions.